# Scala code parser (not compiler)

Tags: parsing, scala

I need to create converter from Scala to another language. I'm looking for scala code parser that converts code to syntax tree without compilation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me make it simple: there is no way to generate a Scala program's AST with parser alone. It is absolutely necessary to run the typer, and that means type inference and implicits.

After that, you can do whatever you want. But these first few phases of the compiler (four on most recent versions, counting the typer) are necessary.

Coincidentally, that's the phases ran by the [presentation compiler](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interactive/Global.html), which is used by the [Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://www.scala-ide.org/). It seems to me that this might be the perfect interface for you.

[ENSIME](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime) also [uses it](http://ensime.blogspot.com/2010/08/building-ide-with-scala-presentation.html), which seems to be the best source of information about it, and you might also want to take a look at the [Scala Refactoring](http://scala-refactoring.org/) tool, since it uses the compiler's AST as well.

Finally, you can try compiling the code with `-Ybrowse:typer` to see the tree after typer. Use `-Xshow-phases` to display the existing phases, or `-Xprint:typer` to print the "source" after typer (or any other phase).

Comment: I think your basic answer is misleading.  If you have a grammar, you can generate an AST; after all, grammars and (syntax) trees are about pure syntax.    I agree, you often need type information to interpret the AST usefully.   (I'm not objecting to your pointers to useful machinery).

Comment: @Ira That assumes the language can be _parsed_ with a grammar. Perl, for example, [cannot](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=663393). On Scala, the jury is still out -- some people have tried to build a parser based on the specifications EBNF, but have found out it doesn't quite work. Maybe Scala can be parsed from a grammar, but, in practice, any such parsing would be _useless_ without typer, since part of the source code is provided implicitly by that phase.

Comment: This same story has been told about C++, too.  It is wrong.  What is true is that some of the parses may be ambiguous locally.  They may even be highly ambiguous, locally.  Mostly what this means is the parsing technology people use (LL(k) and LALR(1)) is pretty lousy at this.  That doesn't mean that the right parsing technology is lousy.  See GLR parsing, which handles such ambiguitites with aplomb.  We parse C++ this way in spite of the folk theorems about it being "hard".   We are working on a Perl parser but its back burner.  I have trouble believing Scala is as nasty as Perl.

Comment: @Ira So you have no experience parsing neither Scala nor Perl, but you feel entitled to discount the formal proof provided for Perl and state as truth that Scala can be parsed because of things that people said about C++ that turned out not to be true?

Comment: We have most of a Perl parser completed, using the same parsing technology we use for C++. Yes, there are constructs that are ambiguous (can be interpreted multiple ways). The "Perl isn't parsable" proof insists on picking a unique parse for Randal Schwartz's fragment. You don't have to do that; you can parse it all the ways that are valid and be done with it.  This leaves resolution of which syntax is *valid* until the code is executed, true.  You still have a parse.  C++ isn't different in this pure parsing sense.