# Scala Help needed - Code completion

Tags: scala, code-completion

I am working on writing an IDE for Scala and need some help. I would like to implement coding assistance so that I could present a list of options when a user presses a period (".") or a space (" "). e.g. if projects is a List, as soon as user types "projects." or "projects ", I would like to show all methods of scala.List that he could use (regular IDE stuff). I know that scala.tools.nsc.interactive package provides this capability, but I am unable to figure out how to do it.  Besides, it seems that the interactive package would use REPL and would be slow for this purpose. Is that a fair assumption, and if yes, are there any alternatives?

Also, is there a way I could get a call reference tree for a literal/ method (where all is the method referred to in a code base) ?

Thanks and Best regards
Aishwarya

Comment: The interactive package does not use the REPL. The REPL stuff is mostly `scala.tools.nsc.interpreter`. What I like about the concept of having a presentation compiler is that when upgrading scala versions it will always support the latest language syntax because it's shipped as part of the compiler. It's designed to be fast for interactive use. I think it can really be a building block for having excellent Scala support in a variety of editors and IDE.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I implemented code completion in https://github.com/asinghal/SlateIDE/blob/master/src/net/slate/editor/completion/ScalaCodeCompletor.scala (just in case anyone ever needs it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your best bet is going through the same set of links I provided in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828728/scala-code-parser-not-compiler), even though the questions are different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the presentation compiler under `scala.tools.nsc.interactive` is where the reusable functionality would be.

The presentation compiler is used by Eclipse and [ENSIME](https://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime). May be ENSIME itself which in addition to providing emacs support also provides a server as a backend for an editor would be a good avenue.

The presentation compiler is not slow. It was designed from the ground up to provide good performance for Eclipse and it has largely delivered on this goal.

For some of the presentation compiler capabilities, see [scala.tools.nsc.interactive.CompilerControl](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interactive/CompilerControl.scala).

For another project using ENSIME, look at [Daniel Spiewak's plugin](https://github.com/djspiewak/ensime-sidekick) for jEdit.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! Let me try these and I'll update the group.